# how to form group of same values and keys

Tags: groovy

1. In groovy, I am having a list of maps.Each map contains 3 keys with
   respective values like:

   ```
   def group= [] as DataList
   def groupRequiredMap = ["a": Metadata.groupName,
                           "b": Metadata.instance,
                           "c": Metadata.color]
       group << groupRequiredMap
   ```

   The Output of group is as follows::

   ```
   [[a:apple, b:0, c:red],
   [a:apple, b:0, c:green],
   [a:apple, b:0, c:blue],
   [a:apple, b:1, c:brown],
   [a:apple, b:1, c:violet],
   [a:grapes, b:0, c:black],
   [a:grapes, b:0, c:yellow],
   [a:grapes, b:1, c:orange],
   [a:grapes, b:1, c:pink]]
   ```

I want to form a group of apple with b=0, a group of apple with b=1, a group of grapes with b=0 and a group of grapes with b=1 and so on.I want Output like this:

```
[[a:apple, b:0, c:[red, green, blue]], 
 [a:apple, b:1, c:[brown,violet]], 
 [a:grapes, b:0, c:[black,yellow]],
 [a:grapes, b:1, c:[orange,pink]]
```

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? Do you have some code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
List list = [[a:'apple', b:0, c:'red'], [a:'apple', b:0, c:'green'], [a:'apple', b:0, c:'blue'], [a:'apple', b:1, c:'brown'], [a:'apple', b:1, c:'violet'], [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'black'], [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'yellow'], [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'orange'], [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'pink']]

List result = []    

list.groupBy ({it.a},{it.b}).each { a ->
    a.value.each { b ->
        result << [a: a.key, b: b.key, c: b.value.c]
    }
}

result
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton Hlinistry this is exactly what i want, but if we have 4 map instead of 3.will it works?like: def groupRequiredMap = ["a": Metadata.groupName,
                        "b": Metadata.instance,
                        "c": Metadata.color,        "d":Metadata.required]

Comment: List list = [[a:'apple', b:0, c:'red', d:'required'], [a:'apple', b:0, c:'green', 'required'], [a:'apple', b:0, c:'blue',d:"optional], [a:'apple', b:1, c:'brown',d:required], [a:'apple', b:1, c:'violet',d:optional], [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'black',d:'required'], [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'yellow',d:'optional'], [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'orange',d:'required'], [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'pink', d:'optional']]

Comment: Depends on how are you going to handle "d".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `each` and mutating a list, you can do:

```
def list =   [[a:'apple', b:0, c:'red'],
              [a:'apple', b:0, c:'green'],
              [a:'apple', b:0, c:'blue'],
              [a:'apple', b:1, c:'brown'],
              [a:'apple', b:1, c:'violet'],
              [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'black'],
              [a:'grapes', b:0, c:'yellow'],
              [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'orange'],
              [a:'grapes', b:1, c:'pink']]

List result = list.groupBy({it.a}, {it.b}).collectMany { aValue, groupA ->
    groupA.collect { bValue, values -> [a: aValue, b: bValue, c:values] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is the first thing you want to go with.  So your key for the grouping is the `subMap("a","b")` - a map, that only holds the key/values for the "a" and "b" key of the original map.  After that you combine the "key map" with a new map containing all the "c"s via the spread-operator `*.`.

```
list.groupBy{ it.subMap("a","b") }.collect{ k, ms -> k + [c: ms*.c] }
```